# Elementary integral question

Tags: calculus

If you have $f(x)= \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}dx $ 
then the elementary integral specifies this is equal to $ln|x+\sqrt{x^2 +3}| $

Which is perfectly fine, I can get there using trigonometric substitution.

But why is this wrong?
$x^2 +3=t , 0.5dt=dx$

$\int\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}dt = \sqrt{t}=\sqrt{x^2+3}$

Im tired, so i might miss something obvious.

Like the
$\int\frac{1}{x}dx $ would end up being $\frac{1}{0}x^0$ will f(x)= $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}dx$ also end up as something over $0$

if the substitution method is used??? Is this a really stupid question?

Comment: i don't see any  hyperbolic function.

Comment: It's not relevant to the question. It's not about how to do it, it's about why doesn't this work.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam That logarithm is the inverse hyperbolic sine of...something (what?)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is with the differentials:

$$x^2+3=t\implies 2xdx=dt\implies dx=\frac{dt}{2x}=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t-3}}$$

Comment: Right, now i feel stupid. Ever have those moments when you look at something and you are blind to the obvious mistake because its too obvious?

Comment: @ArneMorten More than you can imagine. Don't worry.

Comment: There are things interesting when we compare education systems. Whan I was young (loong time ago), what we were teached are things like $x^2+3=t$, $x=\sqrt{t-3}$, $dx=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t-3}}$. Now replace in $ \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So are and were we taught things like that one, my dear Claude. What makes you think othewise?

Answer (score 0):

put $x=\sqrt{3}sh(u)$
then

$ dx=\sqrt{3}ch(u)du$.

using

$ch^2(u)-sh^2(u)=1$,

the integral becomes

$\int du=u+C=argsh(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})+C=ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+3})+K$

where $C$ and $K$ are constants.

Comment: This the OP did, as you can see, and this wasn't his question.